# Checking the data in the file and only accepting the required number of parameters to calculte the area using bash script

Tags: bash, parameters

Part 1) My script allows the command line options -r, -c, and -t for rectangle, circle and trapezoid respectively.  The rectangle option requires two arguments, the length and the width.  The circle option requires one argument, the radius.  The trapezoid option requires three arguments, the height and each of the parallel bases. 
Part 2) The script allows the option, -f.  When this option is used in conjunction with -r, -c, or –t, each option takes one argument, the name of the input file.  The input values would be read from the input file one line at a time and the areas printed to stdout. The script should terminate when a value of –1 is read.

I have part 1 and part 2 both done except the script terminating when -1 is read. What I want to do on the second part is for the rectangle when i give it an input file is to check whether that file has 2 values in each line or not. If it does not have 2 values then echo "file has invalid set(s) of data". Same with circle, it should not accept anything that has more or less value than 1 in each line of th input file and for trapezoid 3.

```
        filename=$OPTARG;;
        while read -a line
        do
            if (( $choice == 1 ))
                    then
                            Area=`echo "scale=3; ${line[0]}*${line[1]}" | bc`;
                            echo "Area of the rectangle is $Area";

            fi
            if (( $choice == 2 ))
                    then
                            Pi=3.1416
                            Area=`echo "scale=3; ${line[0]*$line[0]}*$Pi" | bc`;
                            echo "Area of the circle is $Area";

            fi
            if (( $choice == 3 ))
                then
                            Area=`echo "scale=3; (${line[0]}+${line[1]})/2*${line[2]}" | bc`;
                            echo "Area of the trapezoid is $Area";

            fi
            done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

just grep for -1 in the file and echo $?. This will be zero if -1 is present and 1 if -1 is not present.

To check the no. of values passed do the following

```
SEPERATOR=" ";
#Assumed that seperator is space in your case
#remove all ending spaces
sed -i 's/ *$//g' $filename
#take the count of columns seperated by spaces
cat $filename | grep -o " " | wc -l
#this value +1 gives you the total values in the file
```

Hope this hellps

Comment: im not asking about the -1 i can do it on my own. What I want is when reading a file to calculate the area of the specified objects, the parameters in each line should not be less or more than required. I need 2 for rectangle (length and width), 1 for circle(radius) and 3 for trapezoid (base1, base2 and height). Suppose i have a file bob with the following data 
2 3
2 4
2 8 then running the circle command in it should give me error but running the rectangle will give me the area.

Comment: Sorry, I mis interpreted your question. just count the total columns in the file seperated by space. Dont forget to remove the spaces at end. I have edited my answer to reflect this change